# How to create git dev branch with same name as earlier deleted dev branch?

Tags: git, github

i have to rename a dev branch from lets say **testing** to **tom** . After renaming it i have to create a dev branch with same name that is **testing** and it should point to the specific commit of master.

I have renamed the branch like:

**git branch -m testing tom**  //renamed the branch locally

**git push --set-upstream origin tom** //Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote

**git push origin :testing**       // Delete the old branch

1. I am not able to understand in which branch i should be while doing this : master or dev branch ?
2. Now to create a dev branch should i just use :
   git branch testing .
3. After creating the branch testing will it have same data as in master or do i have to 
   git pull

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git branch -m testing tom             # rename local branch 'testing' to 'tom'

git push origin tom                   # push 'tom' out to the repository

git checkout master                   # switch to the 'master' branch

git branch testing                    # create a new 'testing' branch based on 'master'

git push origin testing --force       # overwrite the 'testing' branch on remote
```

If you follow this set of commands, you don't need to explicitly delete the `testing` branch from the remote because it gets overwritten.